# How to select rows which has cumulative sum of column value min to given value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to fetch data from PostgreSQL, where I need to select rows on below condition.

```
id  type  total_quantity created_dttm [desc]
1    1    10            30-Jun-2021
2    1    12            27-Jun-2021
3    1    32            26-Jun-2021
4    1    52            25-Jun-2021
```

Need to get all rows [sum of total_quantity column value] matching the given value in a query and type. If I give value as 24 and type as 1, then I need to get all rows [cumulative value of total_quantity value] <= 24 and also get next immediate row which is greater than the given value, rest of rows need to be ignored. row[s] are fetched through Order by created_dttm desc
so I need to get only three rows.. for given value 24 and for type = 1.

```
id  type  total_quantity created_dttm [desc]

1    1    10         30-Jun-2021  [10 less than 24 ] fetch row
2    1    12         27-Jun-2021  [22 (sum of current row &previous) less than 24]fetch row
3    1    32         26-Jun-2021  [54 [10+12+32]greater than 24] when greater than reached; 
                                  then fetch this row only
4    1    52         25-Jun-2021   [query should not fetch this row, since max reached @ id 3]
```

I tried sum of two columns, but this will not work, since I am looking for rows between a value range, and with condition to select all rows less than given value + select next max value of given value.. for the given type...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `SUM` here as an analytic function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(total_quantity) OVER (ORDER BY created_dttm DESC)
                  - total_quantity AS tq_sum
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, type, total_quantity, created_dttm
FROM cte
WHERE tq_sum < 24;
```

### Demo

The above trick (in the CTE) works by sparing the current row's total quantity from the running total.  So the first row to exceed the threshhold of 24 would also be included, because its total quantity would be excluded from the running total.